# C - Struct has too many initializer values

Tags: c, gcc, struct, rectangles, initializer

I have code from another site:

```
typedef struct {
  byte x, y;
} Point;

typedef struct {
  Point topLeft;   /* top left point of rectangle */
  Point botRight;  /* bottom right point of rectangle */
} Rectangle;

byte rectanglesOverlap(Rectangle *Rectangle1, Rectangle *Rectangle2) {
  // If one rectangle is on left side of other
  if (Rectangle1->topLeft.x > Rectangle2->botRight.x || Rectangle2->topLeft.x > Rectangle1->botRight.x)
    return 0;

  // If one rectangle is above other
  if (Rectangle1->topLeft.y < Rectangle2->botRight.y || Rectangle2->topLeft.y < Rectangle1->botRight.y)
    return 0;

  return 1;
}
```

I was under the impression that

```
Rectangle *thisR = {{x, y}, {x+width, y+height}},
        *oldR = {{x2, y2}, {x2+width2, y2+height2}};
```

would be OK to use.
It compiles fine, but the overlap check always returns false (meaning, it returns as if they never overlap even if they do)
So switching to Visual Studio, I got the error on the second point's brace

```
{{x, y}, {
         ^
```

saying that I have "Too many initializer values"
Why is this only an error presented in Visual Studio and not GCC, and can it explain why the overlap code never works for me? I've been looking for the answer to this question for days D:

Comment: You are trying to initialise a pointer. A pointer obviously does not have any struct fields at all. I think perhaps you meant to declare `thisR` and `oldR` as `Rectangle` type and not as pointers to that type.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however, the code still does not work. I'll check to see if visual studio still gives me the error, though

Comment: There are likely other errors in your code that is not shown. But can't help you further since you have not shown complete code. Can only comment on the parts you have shown. If you want further help please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're probably calling some other functions that expect pointers as arguments, but forgot to change `thisR` and `oldR` to `&thisR` and `&oldR`.

Comment: Or you have code like `thisR->topLeft`, now it should be `thisR.topLeft`.

Comment: Well the only thing I'm using these rectangles for is: `if(rectanglesOverlap(&thisR, &oldR))`
There's really nothing left other than what I've shown

Answer (score 1):

OP is trying to incorrectly initialize a pointer with the following
 [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233964/c-struct-has-too-many-initializer-values/35234865#comment58182859_35233964)

```
Rectangle *thisR = {{x, y}, {x+width, y+height}},
          *oldR  = {{x2, y2}, {x2+width2, y2+height2}};
```

---

With C11, if code needs to make a `Rectangle *` in the middle of an equation or assignment, could use a *compound literal*.

```
Rectangle *thisR = &( (Rectangle) {{x, y}, {x+width, y+height}});
```

Doubt if this works with Visual Studio

Else use the old-fashion way.

```
Rectangle tmpR = {{x, y}, {x+width, y+height}};
Rectangle *thisR = &tmpR;
```